# System.Data.DataRowView how can i solve it

Tags: c#

In my code i made a method for each button as an example i have chicken and beef buttons and they have there own methods , when I click the chicken button for the fist time when the form loaded it works it will display in the list-box  but when I click beef button after the chicken it show me a System.ArgumentException .
 How would that be fixed ?

```
private void Chicken()
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select Chicken_Name,WithOrWithout_Name,Chicken_Price from  Tbl_Add  a full outer join tbl_Chicken b ON b.Chicken_ID = a.Chicken_ID full outer join Tbl_WithORWithot c ON a.WorWO_ID = c.WithOrWothout_ID ; ", connection))
      {
          DataTable tbl_Chicken = new DataTable();
          adapter.Fill(tbl_Chicken);

          lst_SHowdata.DisplayMember = "Chicken_Name";
          lstSHowdata2.DisplayMember = "Chicken_Price";

          lst_SHowdata.ValueMember = "Chicken_ID";
          lst_SHowdata.ValueMember = "Beef_ID";

          lst_SHowdata.DataSource = tbl_Chicken;
          lstSHowdata2.DataSource = tbl_Chicken;
      }
}

private void Beef()
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select Beef_Name,WithOrWithout_Name ,Beef_Price from  Tbl_Add a full outer join Tbl_Beef b ON b.Beef_ID = a.Beef_ID full outer join Tbl_WithORWithot c ON a.WorWO_ID = c.WithOrWothout_ID  ; ", connection))
        {
            DataTable tbl_Beef = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(tbl_Beef);

            lst_SHowdata.DisplayMember = "Beef_Name";
            lstSHowdata2.DisplayMember = "Beef_Price";

            lst_SHowdata.ValueMember = "Beef_ID";
            lst_SHowdata.ValueMember = "Chicken_ID";

            lst_SHowdata.DataSource = tbl_Beef;
            lstSHowdata2.DataSource = tbl_Beef;
        }     
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chicken();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Beef();
}
```

And i tried to fix it by making a comment for lines that make the exception

```
//lst_SHowdata.ValueMember = "Chicken_ID";
// lst_SHowdata.ValueMember = "Beef_ID";
```

and kinda had been fixed but i need to click the button twice , when I click it for the first time it will display in the listbox **System.Data.DataRowView**.
 how to fix it and make it display only in the first click ?

Comment: "it show me a System.ArgumentException" <--- any message to go along with that?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cannot bind to the new value member.

Comment: that is the message it show me when the exception shown

Comment: Why do you have beef in your chicken, and chicken in your beef?

Comment: i'm trying to fix the problem with them or without them still an error

Comment: You might take a peek at this. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: thanks , the listbox C# my problem with sql -_-

Comment: I'm seeing the ValueMember as "Beef_ID" and "Chicken_ID", but i don't see it in the datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong. This is how understand it.
You are trying to bind data to list-box on button click.
You have 2 list-box controls to bind to.

Assign datasource first before assigning the members. It cannot bind because it is not given a datasource yet.

```
    private void Chicken()
  {
           using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select   Chicken_Name,WithOrWithout_Name,Chicken_Price from  Tbl_Add  a full outer join tbl_Chicken b ON b.Chicken_ID = a.Chicken_ID full outer join Tbl_WithORWithot c ON a.WorWO_ID = c.WithOrWothout_ID ; ", connection))
      {
            DataTable tbl_Chicken = new DataTable();
            connection.Open(); //opens the connection
            adapter.Fill(tbl_Chicken);
            connection.Close(); //Closes the connection

            lst_SHowdata.DataSource = tbl_Chicken; //assigns a datasource
            lst_SHowdata.DisplayMember = "Chicken_Name"; //assigns display
            lst_SHowdata.ValueMember = "Chicken_ID"; //assigns id


            lst_SHowdata2.DataSource = tbl_Chicken;
            lst_SHowdata2.DisplayMember ="Chicken_Price";
            lst_SHowdata2.ValueMember = "Chicken_ID";

        }
  }

  private void Beef()
  {
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select Beef_Name,WithOrWithout_Name ,Beef_Price from  Tbl_Add a full outer join Tbl_Beef b ON b.Beef_ID = a.Beef_ID full outer join Tbl_WithORWithout c ON a.WorWO_ID = c.WithOrWothout_ID  ; ", connection))
      {
        DataTable tbl_Beef = new DataTable();
        connection.Open();
        adapter.Fill(tbl_Beef);
        connection.Close();

        lst_SHowdata.DataSource = tbl_Beef
        lst_SHowdata.DisplayMember = "Beef_Name";
        lst_SHowdata.ValueMember = "Beef_ID";

        lst_SHowdata2.DataSource = tbl_Beef;
        lst_SHowdata2.ValueMember = "Beef_ID";
        lst_SHowdata2.DisplayMember = "Beef_Price";  
    }     
}
```

Comment: thanks sorry for the late replay , is the DataBind in C# because when i  paste the code dataBind not identified ! , thanks i was trying to solve it but i couldn't

Comment: It is in C#. However, it might not be in the control. Sorry, I was thinking of ListView. You don't actually need the databind. Can you comment the databind lines. and try to run it?

Comment: I have updated the code. Since Databind()  is for ASP controls and don't exist in Forms. Sorry, I should have confirmed that before posting. But my answer remains the same without the line. DataSource go first, then assign the members.

Comment: No it's okay ^^" though your solution helped me ^^ to fix it already but i don't no if it will execute properly ^^". ill but the code down

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because when you try to set the ValueMember to "Bee_Name" the list is bound to tbl_chicken, which doesn't have a Beef_Name in it and it thus - correctly - complains.

To get around this, set the Datasources to tbl_beef and then set the ValueMember.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the valuemember is "Beef_ID" and "Chicken_ID". These are not available in the datatable. You need to change it to "Beef_Name" or include the "Beef_ID" in the sql select statement. 
Also for the same list box you are setting two different value Members.

Answer (score 0):

the right code ^^ it

```
 private void Chicken()
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from  Tbl_Add  a full outer join tbl_Chicken b ON b.Chicken_ID = a.Chicken_ID full outer join Tbl_WithORWithot c ON a.WorWO_ID = c.WithOrWothout_ID ; ", connection))
        {
            DataTable tbl_Chicken = new DataTable();
            connection.Open(); //opens the connection
            adapter.Fill(tbl_Chicken);
            connection.Close(); //Closes the connection

            lst_Menu.DataSource = tbl_Chicken; //assigns a datasource
            lst_Menu.DisplayMember = "Chicken_Name"; //assigns display
            lst_Menu.ValueMember = "Chicken_Name";

            lst_worwout.DataSource = tbl_Chicken;
            lst_worwout.DisplayMember = "WithOrWithout_Name";
            lst_worwout.ValueMember = "WithOrWithout_Name";

            lst_Price.DataSource = tbl_Chicken;
            lst_Price.DisplayMember = "Chicken_Price";
            lst_Price.ValueMember = "Chicken_Price";


        }
    }
```